# How do I access the bioimpedence sensor data in Jawbone 3

Tags: jawbone

According to Jawbone the bioimpedence sensor collects oxygen and respiration data.

Can anyone point me to the right library in the api, as I'm having trouble finding it?

Thanks

Niki

https://jawbone.com/blog/up3-advanced-multi-sensor-technology/

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is not possible to access the BI data directly through the APIs. For approved research projects, there are some options for reviewing BI data on test subjects.

For more details: https://jawbone.com/up/developer/research